# fertilizer grades most in demand: forming the phrase

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose I want to say that three grades of fertilizer produced by a plant were most in demand with the customers during a certain period, implying that other grades were bought in lesser volumes. What would be the most natural way to put it? I've formulated it thus:

> During the period under report, the following compound fertilizer grades **were most in demand** with the customers: 
>   - Grade 1 
>   - Grade 2 
>   - Grade 3

What are other possible ways?

Comment: You might also want to consider using the active voice, e.g. *"During the period under report, the compound fertilizer grades the customers most demanded were Grade 1, Grade 2, and Grade 3."*

Answer (score 2):

When we talk about something *in demand*, it's among consumers only. So, *with customers* is not required I think.

Now others may come up with their versions, here is what ***I*** may prefer.

> During the period under report, the following ***were*** the ***most demanded*** compound fertilizer grades. 
>   During the period under report, the following ***were*** the most ***in-demand*** compound fertilizer grades.

Note that I am using *in-demand* as an adjective modifying the grades.

I found a statement (a native speaker's?) from the [Textile Word](http://www.textileworld.com/Issues/2014/July_August/Features/Big_Success_For_INDEX_14)

> As for *products most in demand,* Duttenhofer said: “Evolon and medical solutions ***were the most demanded*** products. INDEX is focused on medical applications. The target group is very dedicated.”